# How to use scrapy to crawl the details page?

Tags: python, scrapy

How can I use scrapy to crawl the details page? Not the list page. The link is https://ssr1.scrape.center

```
import scrapy
from scrapytutorial.items import ScrapytutorialItem


class FirstprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'firstproject'  
    allowed_domains = ['scrape.com', 'baidu.com'] 
    start_urls = ['https://www.baidu.com']  

    def start_requests(self):
        for page in range(1, 11):
            url = f'https://ssr1.scrape.center/page/{page}'
            # 请求对象
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                headers={
                    'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                    'host': 'ssr1.scrape.center',
                    'Referer': 'https://scrape.center/'
                },
                # 设置响应函数
                callback=self.parse
            )

    
    def parse(self, response):
        """list page"""
        movie_list = response.xpath('//*[@id="index"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]')
        for link in movie_list:
            detail_link = 'https://ssr1.scrape.center' + link.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()[0]  
            yield response.follow(
                url=detail_link,
                callback=self.getdetail
            )
        next_page = 'https://ssr1.scrape.center' + response.xpath('//*[@id="index"]/div[2]/div/div/div/a/button/parent::a/@href').get()  
        if next_page and next_page != "#":
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=next_page,
                callback=self.parse,
            )

    
    def getdetail(self, response):
        """details page"""
        items = ScrapytutorialItem()

        items['name'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="detail"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/h2/text()').get()
        items['address'] = response.xpath('@id="detail"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/text()').get()
        items['times'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="detail"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[3]/text()').get()
        items['timestamp'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="detail"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/span/text()').get()
        items['plot'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="detail"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/p/text()').get()
        yield items
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Decide how to do the pagination, you tried to handle it both in the `start_requests` method and in `parse` method.
2. Your xpath selectors are too lengthy and complicated, you can make them way shorter and readable.
3. In the `allowed_domains` attribute you wrote `scrape.com` but it needs to be `scrape.center`.
4. You're getting an error because `items['address']` xpath is partial.
5. You're using `extract()[0]` instead of `get()`, `extract()` returns a list, and if this list is empty and you're trying to get it's first element you'll get an error.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapytutorial.items import ScrapytutorialItem


class FirstprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'firstproject'
    allowed_domains = ['scrape.center', 'baidu.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.baidu.com']
    headers = {
        'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://ssr1.scrape.center/page/1',
            headers=self.headers
            # 设置响应函数
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        """list page"""
        movie_list = response.xpath('//div[@class="el-card__body"]')
        for link in movie_list:
            detail_link = link.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            if detail_link:
                yield response.follow(
                    url=detail_link,
                    headers=self.headers,
                    callback=self.getdetail
                )

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="next"]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(
                url=next_page,
                headers=self.headers)

    def getdetail(self, response):
        """details page"""
        items = ScrapytutorialItem()
        
        items['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="el-card__body"]//h2/text()').get()
        items['address'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="m-v-sm info"]/span/text()').get()
        items['times'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="m-v-sm info"][1]/span[1]/text()').get()
        items['timestamp'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="m-v-sm info"][last()]/span/text()').get()
        items['plot'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="item el-row"]//p/text()').get()
        yield items
```